# Error fasterxml...MismatchedInputException when run on Heroku: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, jackson

I am using Jackson [1] to de-serialize a json file in a straightforward way.

Conceptually it looks like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.readerFor(DirectionsResponse.class);
DirectionsResponse result = objectReader.readValue(jsonString);
```

This works well on a locally-started Spring-Boot application, but does nót work when running the application as deployed WAR on Heroku. On Heroku, I get the following exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input`.

For some reason - so it seems - the `jsonString` does not remain fully available when run on Heroku, which is strange, because it is read in full before it is passed to the `objectReader`.

Thoughts on how to isolate the issue would be much appreciated.

The jsonString is read from an InputStream like this:

```
InputStream is = DirectionsResponse.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);

// which is used to...

private static String readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }
    return resultStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

[1] - com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0

Comment: How is the value of jsonString populated?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I've added the method to the original question, since adding it here did not allow for any formatting.

Comment: Worth logging `jsonString` to log file and see its value when it is running on Heroku.

Comment: I assume you run your WAR file with webapp-runner on Heroku. What do you use to run your application locally? I suggest you try to run your application locally with webapp-runner as well if you're not doing this already. Maybe this helps to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts. 

I just logged `resultStringBuilder.toString()` before returning the result and guess what...? The full string is returned correctly now. 

The total string was fairly long (480,500 chars), which probably caused the reader to choke on it in context of the web app. I will explore a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This problem disappeared after I added `log.info(length: "+ resultStringBuilder.toString().length());` just before returning `resultStringBuilder.toString()` at the end of the method, so I am closing this question.

Thanks for all the help...!